# Preserve DOM elements position while removing texts

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am looking for a solution where I can remove texts (or replace texts with some characters) in DOM where the position of all DOM elements remain same.

**Background**

My project capture full source code of web pages from sensitive web pages, however, those sensitive data does not matter and need to be removed prior to transmitting to the server. Captured source code will be later used to recreate what Administrator was seeing (without texts)

**Example**

Assume this is a page:

```
<div>Some text here
 <input type="button" value="some other text" />
 <a href="#">some more text</a>
</div>
```

So it will be rendered like this by browser:

some text here [some other text]some more text

I need it to be like this:

------ ------ ------ [------- ------ ------]------- ------- ------

**Current buggy approach**

Currently, I get texts in DOM, count characters between each space, and replace those characters with a dash. unfortunately, it will render like this:

---- ---- --- [---- ----- ----]---- ---- ----

Which as you can see, the position of button and link is completely different from the original.

**Purpose**

The main purpose is to recreate DOM later on for UX purposes, but without any texts transmitted to a server that might contain sensitive information. Texts can be completely removed, replaced with any characters (I used - in this example), replaced with other texts such as "Lorem ipsum", as long as it is completely removed from source code while preserving the exact location of DOM.

It is used to record mouse click and mouse move positions (X, Y) and show them as a click/move heat-map.

**Restrictions**

I am not able to change font or codes on target web pages and each element and page might be using a different font for each element.

**Ideas?**

Looking for help if anyone can come up with an idea about this?
The issue here is that - have different character width than characters used in the real text.

1. I have thought of scrambling words in all sentences therefor preserve final total width of the text. however, someone might be able to reshuffle them back to original word and it is a security/privacy risk.
2. I have thought of replacing with multiple dashes based on each word size (and using it currently), but How to get the size of each word in it's specified DOM element? (as each DOM element might use different font, therefore different size for each character) and it could have big performance issue trying to create a hidden div next to each element with their texts just to try to calculate text width of it.
3. on parent element which have text on it, get computed style for font-size,font-family and letter-spacing and use it in a new div to detect that font's width for space. then put original text on that div and detect width of original text. then divide original text width to space width for that font to detect how many space need to be there to generate same width, and generate those spaces. Issue here is that on some pages that have too many texts, It will be an overkill to browser performance.
4. Your idea?

Comment: You won't be able to do that reliably without wrapping a `span` around `Some text here` (or similar) so that you can set the width of those spans. Which makes what you're showing the admin later not **quite** the same DOM the user was looking at.

Comment: Why does it matter? The user has access to any sensitive information on the page, especially if they are producing it. Doing some sort of smoke an mirror will not change that. Use SSL, and also use an MD5 hash and encrypt the data being sent to the server, and use an anti forgery guid to prevent any sort of odd posting to your server.

Comment: T.J Crowder, Unfortunately DOM cannot be changed in admin side. adding span or anything else, might trigger some unexpected CSS classes and spoil interface showing on admin side.

Travis J, User who have access to sensitive information on page is an authorised user. However Admin who review interaction (clicks) on that page is a UX designer who does not have authorization to access sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
// Select 'div','a' and 'input' elements.
// you can add more elements or even select all '*' 
$('div,a,input').each(function() {
    var contents = $(this).contents();
    if (contents.length > 0) {
        if (contents.get(0).nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            // Remove text from children nodes
            var elementText = $(this)
                .clone()    //clone the element
                .children() //select all the children
                .remove()   //remove all the children
                .end()  //again go back to selected element
                .text();
            // Replace text
            $(this).text(elementText.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}/g, '-')).append(contents.slice(1));
        }
    }  
    // From input tags we will replace value
    if($(this).is('input'))
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}/g, '-'));


});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/825tx1hq/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your effort on making this demo, I've upvoted. Unfortunately, this demo only anonymize the text (Goal #1), however it does not preserve original position of elements in visual DOM (Goal #2)